# Use Jquery for text autoformatting: convert --> to →

Tags: jquery, regex, textfield, keyup, autoformatting

How can I get jquery/javascript to detect when `-->` is typed in a textfield and replace it with `→`?

Would something like the following be the best way of doing this:

```
$("input").on("keyup paste", function() {

  var content = $(this).html(),
  arrow =  "→";
  content = content.replace(regex, arrow);
  $(this).html(content);

});
```

Comment: If you've attempted to find a solution, add that in question.

Comment: I have not attempted to find a solution. I would like to work out the most appropriate way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regex to replace all occurrences of a string.

Note: `input` elements have `value`, use `val()` to get the value of it.

```
$("input").on("keyup paste", function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, val) {
        return val.replace(/-->/g, '→');
    });
});
```

```js
$("input").on("keyup paste", function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, val) {
        return val.replace(/-->/g, '→');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

I'll suggest to use `change` event instead of `keyup`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("input").on("keyup paste", function() {
  var content = $(this).val();
  arrow =  "→";
  content = content.replace(/-->/g, arrow);
  $(this).val(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

Comment: Missed `g` flag on regex. Note that user can paste the content having `-->` any number of times. Without `g` only first occurance will be replaced.

Comment: @Tushar Agreed. Edited. Thx!